# What is the class keyword without a body for?

Tags: c++, class, unreal-engine4

I don't understand what "**class**" means in Unreal C++

```
class USpringComponent* BoomArt;
class UCameraComponent* Camera;
```

As I know the class must have a body, but there is no such thing. Why write a **class**? What is the general logic of this key word?

I'm used to seeing this:

```
class MyClass
{
   // body...
}
```

Why write the class keyword ahead in Unreal C++? Yet again:

```
**class** USpringComponent* BoomArt;
```

Comment: The definition is probably in a different compilation unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class USpringComponent* BoomArt;
```

Declares a variable named `BoomArt`. The type is a `USpringComponent*`, or at least that's what we want the type to be.

Presumably, `class USpringComponent` has no been declared yet, meaning if we wrote `USpringComponent* BoomArt`, we'd get a compilation error ("Unknown type USpringComponent" or something along those lines).

Putting `class` out front just tells the compiler that, even though you haven't defined anything named `USpringComponent` yet, there is a class by that name *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward declare a type without fully defining it. There are limiations on how a forward ddeclared tpye can be used but defining a pointer is one valid use case.

The line

```
class USpringComponent* BoomArt;
```

is equilvalent to

```
class USpringComponent;    // Forward declaration of the class
USpringComponent* BoomArt; // Define a pointer to an object of the class.
```

Related: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: That is, you can declare absolutely without problems without the class keyword or if desired, with it?

Comment: @SamuelRobb The forward declartion must use the keyword `class`. The variable definition can omit the keyword `class` only if the `class` has been forward declared first.